# How to create a flag based on two time based measures?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I have a Power BI file with 4 tables. Customer, Calls, Repairs and Date. I have calculated Total Calls, Previous Month Calls, Total Repairs and Previous Month Repairs. How do I create a flag to catch customers who have calls more than the previous month or Repairs more than the previous month? Repairs and Calls Tables are connected through the customer table

Power BI data model:
[image: powerbi data model]

Power BI table:
[image: powerbi table]

Comment: What do you mean by a "flag" and how do you want it implemented? Another column? Conditional formatting? Filtering?

Comment: I want a Yes/No indicator when Calls Current Month - Calls_last_Month > 0 and another Yes/No indicator when Repair Orders current month - Repairs_Last Month > 0